# Generating Thumbnails for .ppt and .pptx in swing

Tags: java, swing, powerpoint

```
public class SlideThumbnailPanel extends JPanel {
    
    private List<SlidePanel> slides;
    private int currentSlideIndex;
    
    public SlideThumbnailPanel() {
        slides = new ArrayList<>();
        currentSlideIndex = -1;
        //setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 0));
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    public void addSlide() {
        SlidePanel newSlide = new SlidePanel();
        slides.add(newSlide);
        currentSlideIndex = slides.size() - 1;
        ImageIcon thumbnail = createThumbnail(newSlide);
        JLabel thumbnailLabel = new JLabel(thumbnail);
            thumbnailLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 112));
            add(thumbnailLabel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void removeSlide() {
        if (currentSlideIndex >= 0 && currentSlideIndex < slides.size()) {
            slides.remove(currentSlideIndex);
            remove(currentSlideIndex);
            if (slides.size() > 0) {
                currentSlideIndex = Math.max(0, currentSlideIndex - 1);
            } else {
                currentSlideIndex = -1;
            }
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private ImageIcon createThumbnail(SlidePanel slide) {
        BufferedImage thumbnailImage = new BufferedImage(200, 112, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = thumbnailImage.createGraphics();
        slide.paint(g);
        g.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(thumbnailImage);
    }
}
```

Unable to display expected results. When adding a slide, nothing changes the thumbnail and the method `addSlide(`) can be called normally.

Comment: `setLayout(null);` and `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 0));` are not good starting points

Comment: `slide.paint(g);` should probably be `slide.printAll(g)`, but you will need to size the panel to a reasonable size, otherwise nothing gets painted